# create table in latex

Tags: latex, tex

I have created a table in latex with the following code

\begin{tabular}{| c|c|c |}

Carbon dioxide (CO$_2$) & 0.038\%\(0.026\% \footnote{Preindustrial}) & 0.058\% \

however the table i want should be like the one in shown in the picture. with the code above the number 0.026% comes below Co2 and there is no footnote.

[image: the table I like to have]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why this doesn't work, I am not quite sure. You probably just can't use *\footnote* in a tabular environment. However, instead of *\footnote* just try *_*. Note: I changed the code a bit since the *backslashes* etc didn't compile when copied, so I tried to do what I think you meant to do.

```
Carbon dioxide (CO$_2$) & 0.038\%\(0.026\%_{Preindustrial}\) & 0.058\%
```

Edit: Spelling/Emphasis Code

Edit2: Since I just noticed I might have misunderstood your question. Here another answer to maybe what your question was. If this is not correct either, please try to rephrase your questions, so it is understandable.

```
\hline
Carbon dioxide (CO$_2$) & 0.038\% & 0.058\\
& \(0.026\%\) & \\
\hline
```